# Adventureworks joining sales.store with sales.salesorderdetail to pull in store name

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, adventureworks

I'm working on some adventureworks practice queries and am having some issues.

I'm trying to pull in the store name from the sales.store table and add it to the sales.salesorderdetail table so I can see which "stores" are ordering specific items.

MY problem is that I can't seem to find a common key that will allow me to do that unless customerid = businessentityid, which I don't believe it does.

I thought I could use the person.person table to pull this in but since every businessentityid does not necessarily have a "person", I don't think this will work.

Is anyone familiar enough with adventureworks to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from sales.Store
inner join sales.Customer on sales.Store.BusinessEntityID = sales.Customer.StoreID
inner join sales.SalesOrderHeader on sales.Customer.CustomerID = sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID
inner join sales.SalesOrderDetail on sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
```

To find the relationship, right click the Store table in SSMS and View Dependencies. The resulting tree shows that store connects to SalesOrderDetail via Customer and SalesOrderHeader.

[image: Store dependencies]

Also, here's the constraint showing that Store.BusinessEntityID joins to Customer.StoreID:

```
ALTER TABLE [Sales].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Store_StoreID] FOREIGN KEY([StoreID])
REFERENCES [Sales].[Store] ([BusinessEntityID])
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, seems a little convoluted to mix naming conventions and have business entity id = store id, but i figured it had to be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from

(select * from sales.SalesOrderDetail where year(modifieddate)=2012 and month(modifieddate)=3) as x

left join

(select CustomerID, salesorderid from sales.SalesOrderHeader) as y

on y.SalesOrderID=x.SalesOrderID

left join 

(select StoreID, CustomerID from sales.customer) as z

on z.CustomerID=y.CustomerID

left join

(select BusinessEntityID, name from sales.store) as w

on w.BusinessEntityID=z.StoreID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, Orderęty FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
       WHERE Orderoty (SELECT AVE (Order@ty) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.